# OwnCloud and Truecrypt

Tags: sync, truecrypt, dropbox, owncloud

I have tried the [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/) sync software recently and it works pretty nice.

It synchronizes all the files pretty fast, but I am a bit worried about security.

So, my idea was to put my private files into a TrueCrypt container file and then put this container file into an OwnCloud WebDAV folder to have it automatically synced and backed up.

But unlike regular files, my TrueCrypt file container doesn't synchronize with the OwnCloud storage until it is unmounted.

I can make changes to files in the file container and the modification date of this file container changes (`ls -al` clearly shows that), but the file container itself is not synchronized.

It is synchronized only when I dismount my TrueCrypt file container.

Is there any way to fix this strange behaviour of the TrueCrypt file container and sync it with the OwnCloud automatically without dismounting it?

Comment: This is how TrueCrypt works.

Comment: You could secure your connection to your OwnCloud with SSL and encrypt your server. That can be an alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design.  TrueCrypt locks the file container to prevent any other application from accessing the file and potentially corrupting data.  You will have to periodically unmount the container to allow OwnCloud to synchronize the file.